# is Undefined Errors in VS Code MinGW Vs. Win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I am facing a problem with my VSCode.

when i use MinGW it shows me errors of `identifier ... is Undefined` which does not affect the execution of the code,
but when I switch to Win32 all these errors disappears. and that happens even though I included the needed Libraries. I wanna know if some one can help me out What is the problem and how can I solve it.

here are my headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
```

if I write a simple code for example something deals with time like this:

```
int main()
{

    time_t now = time(0);
    cout<<ctime(&now);

    return 0;
}
```

it shows me erros like that only when I use MinGW

```
identifier "make_tuple" is undefined
identifier "get" is undefined
identifier "time" is undefined
identifier "localtime" is undefined
identifier "asctime" is undefined
identifier "ctime" is undefined
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or messages. They are not search friendly. Please post the code and the messages in textual form.

Comment: is it okay now ?! @RSahu

Comment: That's better. It will be better still if you can post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `std::` prefix for those functions.

Instead of `make_tuple`, use `std::make_tuple`, etc.

Comment: I used `using namespace std;` at the first is it enough ? @R Sahu